# document.getElementById does not capture the value

Tags: javascript, html

I've trying to get the value of the input "numLineas", but it just doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Here I give you the code:

```js
var nLineas = parseInt(document.getElementById("numLineas").value);

function prueba(){ 

    window.alert(nLineas);

}
```

```html
<form action=""> 
    <label for="numLineas">Con cuantas lineas deseas dibujar la curva?</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="numLineas"><br>
</form>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="prueba()">Ingresar</button> 
<br>
   
<!--<script src="practica7_CurvaPersonalizada.js"></script>-->
```

In the alert only appears NaN, no matter what I write there (number or string). PLS HELP!

Comment: @Spectric, great edit!

Comment: `window.alert("nLineas");` gives you `NaN` and not `nLineas`?

Comment: Where is your javacript in relation to the HTML? If it's above the markup, you'll have this problem.

Comment: @seesharper OP indicates it's below the markup

Comment: Use your debugger. If you haven’t used your debugger, why not?

Comment: Move your `var nLineas...` line **inside** the `prueba` function and use `alert(nLineas)`, not `alert("nLineas")`

Comment: You're trying to print a string, not the variable.... remove quotes from alert function

Comment: @Phil spotted the problem - or a least the most important one.

Comment: @Phil you're right, actually I was trying literally EVERY OPTION for printing the var content, including the quotes thing (I know it's wrong) but I have no more ideas LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of points here:

- `var nLineas = document.getElementById("numLineas").value;` should be put inside the 'onclick' method to better indicate it is read on a per-click basis.
- Use the method `isNaN` to validate that the value you are reading is an int, before calling `parseInt`
- Using `document.getElementById().onclick=prueba` worked  lot better at assigning the function to that element for me.
- `window.alert("nLineas");` will only ever return `nLineas`. To get the value of the variable you set, use it without quotation marks, like `console.log(nLineas)`

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = prueba;

function prueba() {
  var nLineas = document.getElementById("numLineas").value;
  if (!isNaN(nLineas)) {
    console.log("nLineas is a int");
    nLineas = parseInt(nLineas);
  }
  console.log("nLineas is " + nLineas);
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="numLineas">Con cuantas lineas deseas dibujar la curva?</label><br>
  <input type="text" value="test" id="numLineas"><br>
</form>
<br>
<button id="button" type="button">Ingresar</button>
<br>
<script src="practica7_CurvaPersonalizada.js"></script>
```

Comment: `addEventListener()` is preferable over directly assigning `onclick`

Comment: @Phil I will die on the `onclick =` hill. I picked the habit up after assigning click handlers using `+=` in C#